# UITableView cell creation on Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to create UITableViewCell with swift, on my delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath,

the code is simple as in Objective-c, just trying to morph the language to swift.

I am getting error on this line

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
    }
```

error is UITableViewCell is not convertible to "MirrorDisposition"

I have looked up examples, the code was like this

```
if !cell
{let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
}
```

but it also gives an error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try declaring the variable as optional `var cell:UITableViewCell? = ...` or just let the compiler infer the type `var cell = ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of the latest beta (beta 6) **non optional types cannot be compared with nil**.

Therefore you must declare your cell Var as an Optional.

Something like this will work correctly (off the top of my head - I don't have Xcode in front of me):

```
//declare a tableViewCell as an implicitly unwrapped optional...
var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

//you CAN check this against nil, if nil then create a cell (don't redeclare like you were doing...
if(cell == nil)
{
  cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: `Value of type 'UITableViewCell' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed` In Swift 2.0 i get this error?!

Answer (score 9):

A far better option is to use the more modern method which always returns a cell (as long as you are using a storyboard, or have registered the nib or class for the cell)

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Since the method always returns a cell, it's not an optional, and there as no need to check for nil.

Comment: This times a million! The method being used in the OP should never be used IMHO. Create a UITableViewCell subclass and register it with the table an a reuse identifier. Then let the table create the cell for you.

Comment: Agreed however, I wanted to stick with the paradigm the OP was using. This is a different implementation, rather than an answer as to why his code wasn't working.